# Laravel - how to return json on current page instead of popup window

Tags: laravel, vue.js, oauth

I'm building SPA with Laravel and Vuejs, so I want to let users signin with github on popup window but problem is that authorization callback function returns json data on popup window instead of current page.

Here is a code:

Client side

```
authenticate() {
            window.open("login/github", "_blank", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400");
        }
```

Server side

```
public function redirectToProvider($service, Request $request)
{
    return Socialite::driver($service)->stateless()->redirect();
}

public function handleProviderCallback($service, Request $request)
{
    $providerUser = Socialite::driver($service)->stateless()->user();

    return new JsonResponse([
        'data' => $providerUser
    ]);
}
```

I need to close popup window when user successfully sign in and than `handleProviderCallback` to return json on a current page. Any idea how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Parent window

```
<button type="button" onclick="openNewWindow()">Login With Github</button>
    <script>
        var win = null;
        function openNewWindow() {
            win = window.open("ukulele.html", "_blank", "toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,top=500,left=500,width=400,height=400");
            win.focus();
        }
        window.saveToken = function() {
            console.log(win.document.getElementById('json_data_here').value)
        }
    </script>
```

Child window: After success login with github, save token to a hidden input and close window:

```
<input type="hidden" id="json_data_here" value="aadcs"/>
<script>
    window.opener.saveToken();
    window.close();
</script>
```